# Assertion failure using TAPI (cv::UMat) with big images - OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, opencl, assertion

I get an assertion failure when using the OpenCV TAPI (`cv::UMat`) in the following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cv::extractChannel(img_vec[i], alpha_vec[i], 3);
        cv::cvtColor(img_vec[i], img_vec[i], CV_BGRA2BGR);
    }
```

Code is crashing in the fifth iteration, just after running `cv::cvtColor(img_vec[i], img_vec[i], CV_BGRA2BGR)`.

The output message is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (clEnqueueReadBuffer(q,
>   (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0,
>   0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS) in map, file
>   C:\OpenCV-3.1.0\sources\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line 4758
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information. terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception' what():
>   C:\OpenCV-3.1.0\sources\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp:4758: error: (-215)
>   clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size,
>   alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS in function map

It only happens with big images (> 20Mp). The code is working if I don't use the TAPI (`cv::Mat`) or disabling OpenCL (`cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(false)`). I'm using 3.1.0 version.

Why is this so? Is there any way to make it work with GPU support?